# Event listener isnot working in asynchronous js

Tags: javascript

I know why it shows error because due to asynchronous, button is not loaded yet. Is there any way to fix it? I cannot explain much in words. At the time window is loaded , there is no button because it appears only after clicking id. i tried to put all codes but stack overflow requires much explanation

This is my main js code. Fetch works and i didnot include all codes.

```
const controlMovie = async()=> {

const id = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');

if(id){
    // new id
    clearMovie();
    state.control = new Control(id);
    await state.control.getMovies();
   
    
UImovie(state.control);
}
return id;
};

const viewList = async()=>
{
    const id = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');
    state.view= new Control(id);
    await state.view.getMovies();
    UIlist(state.view);
}





['hashchange', 'load'].forEach(event => window.addEventListener(event, controlMovie));


document.querySelector('.add').addEventListener('click', viewList);
```

This is for UI js part

```
const UImovie = (info)=> {
    const markup = `
    <div class="img-fig">
    <img src="${info.image}" alt="${info.title}" class="movie-img">
    </div>
    
   <div class="movie_details">
    
           <br>
           <h3 style="align-items: center; font-weight: bold;"> ${info.title}</h3>
        <p>Writer: ${info.writer}</p>
               <p>Released date: ${info.year}</p>
               <p>Actors: ${info.actors} </p>
               <p>imdbRating: ${info.rating}</p>
               <p>Total seasons: ${info.seasons}</p>
               <p style="font-style: italic; color: red; font-size: 16px;"> "${info.story}"</p>
               <button class= "add">+ Add to watchlist</button>
              
           </div>
       </div>
    `;
   document.querySelector('.movies-result').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', markup);
};
const UIlist = (UI)=> {
    const markup = `
    <h3> ${UI.title} <button class="icons"><ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon></button></h3>
    `;
    document.querySelector('.lists').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', markup);
}
```

Comment: @Rajesh i have updated. plz look  again and help me

Comment: Please do not update question's details based on suggestions. In your original code, you were adding listener on `.icons`. Now its adding on `.add`. It renders comment/ answer void

Comment: i am sorry. There was mistake in code , so i updated. can you help me now?

Comment: First, no need to apologize to anyone. I was just giving you a caveat. Second, either way your problem is same and I have added a solution based on original question. Please take reference from it and update your code. It should help you resolve it. If you have any doubts/ queries, feel free to add comment

Answer (score 0):

As commented, based on the provided code, you are added `.icons` dynamically. but `.addEventListener` is being executed during pageload. Due to this, when its executed, there is no elements available on DOM and no listener is added.

You should try using HTMLElement objects instead:

```js
const UIlist = (UI)=> {
  const h3 = document.createElement('h3');
  h3.innerText = UI.title;
  const button = document.createElement('button');
  const icon = document.createElement('ion-icon');
  icon.setAttribute('name', 'trash');
  button.append(icon);
  button.classList.add('icons');
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('Button Clicked');
  })
  h3.append(button)
  document.querySelector('.lists').insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', h3);
}

UIlist( { title: 'Bla' } )
```

```html
<div>
  <div class='lists'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: **Note:** This answer is based on original question. I'm not changing it as the issue is same and this should be considered as an reference point for usecase